# What's a good level to solo a co-op mission?

Tags: lego-batman

Lego Batman has a "Sidekick" achievement, for completing a level in co-op.  I don't have anyone I want to call on to play with me, so I'm looking to complete it myself.  (In the same way, I completed the equivalent "Aye-aye, captain!" achievement from Lego Pirates of the Carribean on Port Royale.)

What's a good level to do this on?  It would be one where most of the puzzles / tasks can be completed single-handedly (Obviously, levels where character A presses a switch lifting the door in front of character B and then character B turns a dial so character A can keep moving etc is sub-optimal...), and where the second character warps to me when I switch rooms, so I don't need to navigate  the room with each character separately (so I don't have to keep switching controllers).

Comment: Is is possible that you don't have to complete the entire level with the other character active? IE you only need to add them right before you complete the level to get the achievement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this in the first level of the first story (You Can Bank On Batman), relatively easy.
According to [XboxAchievements](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/lego-batman/achievement/18238-Sidekick-.html), you need to have the second controller switched on before you enter the level - it is what I did.

According to the same source, you can get this on the bonus levels as well.
I'm currently trying it in the Wayne Manor bonus level, but I don't recommend this one. Although there are no enemies to kill your extra character, it's a pain when you get to the area with the water, where you have to roll balls over sprinklers. If the characters move too far apart, the screen goes dark. So you constantly have to get the other controller to move your second character to where the first is.

**Update**: you can get this in the Arkham Asylum bonus level - just managed it. So, bonus levels count for this one. You'll need the 2nd controller occasionally as the characters aren't allowed to move too far apart. And the 2nd controll will be buzzing all the time as your 2nd character gets killed all the time by the wandering lunatics.
I recommend using the "You Can Bank On Batman" level, not one of the two bonus levels.